# what is the method or class that is generating access token and refresh token in django oauth2_provide

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I am trying to create an api that will generate an oauth2_provider access token and refresh token, and it will store in oauth2_provider models. Actually i am using below API to generate both tokens

path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),

But what i want to do is create an api and store custom generated tokens in that models.
for ex:

```
access_token = oauth2_provide.<some class name that is generating tokens>
```

Is there any class names or methods that are acting behind the scenes to generate those tokens? if any are there pls let me know.

thanks in advance.